# Upgrading NPM from 5.8 to latest

Tags: npm, npm-update

I want to look at upgrading NPM on a project I'm working on from 5.8.0 to the latest version.

Is this something that is safe to do without breaking any packages i have installed? And if there's a chance it might, what is the best method for testing those packages to make sure everything is running correctly still?

Answer (score 0):

Updating NPM is unlikely to break anything. However your packages may require a certain version of Node.js to function properly.

There also isn't really a "best method" to check if everything runs correctly. Ill refer you to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61648811/if-i-have-source-code-and-macos-and-windows-installers-for-an-app-how-can-i-fin/61706186#61706186) which has a few options you can try.